# well pump will not fill pressure tank

Tags: water, septic, pressure

Just installed a Wayne WLS150 water sprinkler pump in addition to a 20 gallon pressure tank on our boat dock. The tank has a 40-60 pressure switch on it. Pump works well and pumps an enormous amount of water through a 1 inch poly discharge pipe. The problem is the tank never fills. The pressure gauge reads a constant 40 PSI. and runs constantly even if I shut the valve just beyond the tank. My research shows the pump specified discharge is 30 PSI @ 2700 gallons an hour. I'm thinking the pump does not supply enough pressure to fill the tank and is designed to operate on demand for sprinkler system.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. If you'll take the [tour], you'll see that this is a Question & Answer board, and, frankly, I don't see where you've asked a question. It looks like you were thinking out loud. If you'd care to [edit] your post to make the question more explicit, I'm sure you'll get plenty of help.

Comment: "constant 40 PSI" - if that's the case even when it's shut off and drained, you have a broken gauge. If that's not the case, it's not "constant." If you have the usual Square-D pumptrol, You can **shut off the power at the breaker,** open the case and adjust it to work at a lower pressure (40-60 is just a preset before they put it in the box) - if you have some other pressure switch that might or might not be true. Read the instruction sheet it was packaged with. If your pump will go to 40 PSI, adjusting it down to 20-40 (and lowering precharge in the tank to 17-18) might work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I looked up the specs for your pump and it's a high volume irrigation pump, not a pressure pump.  It's not designed to build pressure. And why even bother with a 20 gal pressure tank? It might be able to build enough pressure for the pressure switch to shut it off if you lower it enough.

Your last sentence in your OP is correct.   If you are using it with an irrigation system and a controller, many can support a "master relay dry contact" to turn on the pump.

Edit:  Just re-read your question. What are you using the pump for on a boat dock?  To hose down the deck, hull, etc? Fill tanks for domestic water use? Hose down the dock?   Given the pump you have, you may have to install a simple disconnect to shut off the pump completely when not needed.